# Time complexity of a prefix sum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, prefix-sum

Given the following pseudo code, I'm wondering if my thought process is correct when trying to determine the time complexity.

```
for i = 0 to n-1
   Add the numbers A[0] thru A[i].
   Store the result in B[i].
```

The algorithm will loop n times, and since the last iteration will require the most amout of computations (n computations) the algorithm will in total make `n^2 + f(n)` computations. where `f(n)` is a polynomial of degree `n^2` ***or less.*** Therefore this algorithm is quadratic `O(n^2)`.

Comment: But `B[i] = B[i-1]+a[i]`, no sane implementation would repeat the entire partial summation at each iteration.  Your algorithm may be `O(n^2)` but prefix summation isn't.

Comment: It is not supposed to be sane, it's only an exercise in time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the time complexity of `Add the numbers A[0] thru A[i].` is `\Theta(i)`, the time complexity of your code would be `\Theta(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + \Theta(n)) = \Theta(n^2)`. Hence, your analysis for your code is true.

Answer (score 0):

we can replace your code with the following code

```
    for i 0 to n - 1
        for j 0 to i
            b[i] += a[j]   <---
```

In order to find the big O of this algorithm we need to calculate how many
times the 3rd row is executed.

just for simplicity lets say all a[i] elements equal to 1 
so if we find the sum of b[i] when i is 0 to n -1 
then we find the number of time the 3rd line was run.

```
i: b[i]
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
..
n - 1: n
```

therefore the total sum of all B[i] is n * (n + 1) / 2
which is O(n^2)